# mod_rewrite not working as expected on AT&T shared hosting service

Tags: mod-rewrite, att

New to mod_rewrite and have searched the net and Apache docs with no results so far.  I'm trying to test the functionality of mod_rewrite on an AT&T Web Services host, using the following rewrite rule in an .htaccess file inside a subdirectory:

RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^test.html$ test.php

Upon navigating to "/mod_rewrite_test/test.html", the result from the browser is: "The requested URL /a/b//public/mod_rewrite_test/test.php was not found on this server."

The rule is being read, because I can clear out the .htaccess file and "/mod_rewrite_test/test.html" loads the test.html file I created.  This simple test works fine on another hosting provider I have access to.  Any thoughts on why the rewrite URL has the "/a/b/" and "/public" additions to it?

Answer (score 0):

True to form, I finally stumbled upon an answer shortly after asking the question.  Adding this to the .htaccess worked:

RewriteBase /mod_rewrite_test/

Odd that the rewrite works on a different host without that addition.